# Create folder in windows event viewer using C#

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

In my current installer I am creating event log for each application version. Doing so there are lots of events created for each version. Searching for correct event log is bit difficult for clients. So I want to do something like what Microsoft does.

I want to create a main folder with my company's name and inside it folder for major version 
`Sample:
ABC Corp.

```
  App 4.0
     all event logs
  App 5.0
     all event logs`
```

[image]Like in image Microsoft->Windows

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'am wrong, but maybe you could use:

```
EventSourceCreationData eventSourceData = new EventSourceCreationData("Application","Application");
```

Comment: Sorry its not working. It simply creates an event log. I want to create a folder structure and inside it event log